# Wordpress: preg_replace inside a loop only works occasionally

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to make a **custom RSS feed** with some **alteration to the HTML content** of each post.

Inside the template file `rss-custom.php` I have this:

```php
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
  <?php echo processPostContent(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

in `functions.php`, there are **three** replacements as follows :

```php
function processPostContent() {
    $post = get_post(get_the_ID());
    $post_content = strval($post->post_content);
    // replace h3 and h4 tags with h2
    $post_content = preg_replace('/<(\/?)h((?![12])\d)/im', "<$1h2", $post_content);
    // strip every attribute of <img> other than src
    $post_content = preg_replace('/<img[^>]*(src="[^"]*")[^>]*>/im', "<img $1 />", $post_content);
    // insert text after some closing tags
    $post_content = preg_replace('/<\/(h2|p|figure)>/im', "</$1><p>Inserted</p>", $post_content);

    return $post_content;
}
```

Then I get a strange result: out of 20 posts, only 7-8 of them will have been fully replaced. The remaining get the first two replacements but not the third one. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Have you tried running the 3 `preg_replace` on 1 post manually that appears not to work in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, turns out, doesn't have anything to do with the loop nor `preg_replace`. Some posts' contents do not include any HTML tag, only plain text. That's why `preg_replace` didn't have any effect on them. When those contents are rendered in the RSS feed, however, `<p>` tags are ***automatically*** inserted. That's what led me to believe the third replacement was skipped.

```html
First paragraph.
Second paragraph.
```

is turned to

```html
<p>First paragraph.</p>
<p>Second paragraph.</p>
```